# Defining the size of a picturebox

Tags: vb6

I'm using the code from this project in VB6:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?394360-VB-Showing-the-CPU-graph-like-in-Windows-Task-Manager

But the picture box becomes 100% of the form, how can I define the size of it?

Comment: So, are you using VB 6 or VB.NET? You have both tags applied to your question, but they're *very* different languages and not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB.NET your picturebox object ought to have a SIZEMODE property, try changing that

In VB6 (I cant remember for sure but it might be called something like..) AUTOSIZE?  try changing that

once you change that property it should use the Width/Height parameters instead of autosizing, so will may need to set those (width/height) again or resize them when a form_resize occurs.

## Update

After reviewing your code sample i can see that THIS line defines the SIZE

```
picCPUGraph.Move(45, 45, Me.ScaleWidth - 90, Me.ScaleHeight - 90)
```

So if you change this to....
style-1

```
picCPUGraph.Move(45, 45, Me.ScaleWidth - 90, (Me.ScaleHeight - 90)/2)
```

OR
style-2

```
picCPUGraph.Move(45, 45, Me.ScaleWidth - 90, (Me.ScaleHeight - 90)/3)
```

Or 
style-3

```
picCPUGraph.Move(45, 45, Me.ScaleWidth - 90, (Me.ScaleHeight - 90)/4)
```

That will STOP your picture box from filling the form client area.

Style 1 will use HALF the vertical space
Style 2 will use ONE THIRD the vertical space
Style 3 will use ONE QUARTER the vertical space

Comment: Thank you for the help, I had actually tried that but no luck. I believe the way the original coder wrote it is making it do this. Here is the source code for the main form:

http://www.pastebin.ca/2333730

Comment: Hiya again, Please may I know? what is the SCALEMODE setting of your "picCPUGraph" PictureBox?

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I applied it to the height and width and it's doing what I want. I'll have to play around to find out the exact number I need but this works, thank you again.

Scalemode is set to pixel

Comment: Oh thats VERY strange indeed! because as far as I can remember, only when the SCALEMODE is set to TWIPS do you divide by 15 because roughly 15 twips = 1 pixel or thats what I remember though it has been many years since I used VB6. And in the FORM_RESIZE procedure i recall there were quite a few lines where the numbers were being divided by 15. Oh well the main thing is that you can continue with your program now. Note: when the SCALEMODE is pixel you can set them directly without dividing by 15